# JavaScript with Timeout Function

Tags: javascript, timeout

I am trying to display a counter at the

element with #showText as ID.  However, no matter what, the #showText element never appear.  I have explanations of the codes below.  Can anyone help me to make the #showText element display?

```js
var counter = 0;

// Call the update function 2 seconds after first load.  
timeoutID = window.setTimeout("Update();", 2000);

function Update() {
  counter++;
  var textField = document.getElementById("showText");
  /* The value counter changes once every 2 seconds.  */
  textField.innerHtml = "The counter is now at " + counter;

  // Set another timeout for the next count, function calls itself.  
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout("Update();", 2000);
}

// Set event listeners for the buttons.  
document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter = 0; // Reset counter to 0.  
  Update(); // Call Update() method to start counting from 0.  
});

// Clears time out for timeID, which means Update() will no longer be invoked, and counter stops increasing.  
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
});
```

```html
<h1>Timeout Example</h1>
<p>The counter will update every two seconds. </p>
<p>Press RESTART or STOP to restart or stop the count. </p>
<p id="showText"></p>
<section>
  <button type="button" id="restart">RESTART</button>
  <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>
</section>
```

Comment: @Olian04 It doesn't work, I changed both setTime method's first parameter.

Comment: look at my answer, you had missed that HTML should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

1. change `setTimeout("Update();", 2000)` to `setTimeout(Update, 2000)`
2. change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML`

```js
var counter = 0;

// Call the update function 2 seconds after first load.  
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Update, 2000);

function Update() {
  counter++;
  var textField = document.getElementById("showText");
  /* The value counter changes once every 2 seconds.  */
  textField.innerHTML = "The counter is now at " + counter;

  // Set another timeout for the next count, function calls itself.  
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Update, 2000);
}

// Set event listeners for the buttons.  
document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter = 0; // Reset counter to 0.  
  Update(); // Call Update() method to start counting from 0.  
});

// Clears time out for timeID, which means Update() will no longer be invoked, and counter stops increasing.  
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
});
```

```html
<h1>Timeout Example</h1>
<p>The counter will update every two seconds. </p>
<p>Press RESTART or STOP to restart or stop the count. </p>
<p id="showText"></p>
<section>
  <button type="button" id="restart">RESTART</button>
  <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Click the `RESTART` button 3 or 4 times and you'll find that it will start counting up quicker and quicker as multiple `Update` functions are created.

Comment: @MT0 yea... but that wasn't the question. The question was "Can anyone help me to make the #showText element display?"

Answer (score 0):

Your textField.innerHTML had a syntax error; you wrote innerHtml. I also removed the orphan function call, as you would want it to only run on button press I presume. Correcting that, now it works -the STOP button as well -:

```js
    var counter = 0;

    function Update() {
      counter++;
      var textField = document.getElementById("showText");
      /* The value counter changes once every 2 seconds.  */
      textField.innerHTML = "The counter is now at " + counter;

      // Set another timeout for the next count, function calls itself.  
      timeoutID = window.setTimeout("Update();", 2000);
    }

    // Set event listeners for the buttons.  
    document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function() {
      counter = 0; // Reset counter to 0.  
      Update(); // Call Update() method to start counting from 0.  
    });

    // Clears time out for timeID, which means Update() will no longer be invoked, and counter stops increasing.  
    document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    });
```

```html
    <h1>Timeout Example</h1>
    <p>The counter will update every two seconds. </p>
    <p>Press RESTART or STOP to restart or stop the count. </p>
    <p id="showText"></p>
    <section>
      <button type="button" id="restart">RESTART</button>
      <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>
    </section>
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please feel free to upvote and mark as solution so we get our points as well ;)

Comment: If you click `RESTART` multiple times then it will start counting up faster than every two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`;
- `innerHTML` or `innerText` rather than the (invalid) `innerHtml`;
- separate out the logic for starting, stopping, showing the counter and updating the counter to make it clearer what is being run and when and to make sure you do not have additional timers spawned:

```js
var counter = 0;
var isCounting = false;
var timeoutID = null;
var textField = document.getElementById("showText");

function Stop() {
  if ( timeoutID )
  {
    self.clearInterval( timeoutID );
  }
}

function Start()
{
  Stop();
  counter = 0;
  timeoutID = self.setInterval(Update, 2000); 
  Show();
}

function Show()
{
  textField.innerText = counter;
}

function Update() {
  counter++;
  Show();
}

// Set event listeners for the buttons.  
document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click",  Start );
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", Stop );
```

```html
<h1>Timeout Example</h1>
<p>The counter will update every two seconds. </p>
<p>Press RESTART or STOP to restart or stop the count. </p>
<p id="showText"></p>
<section>
  <button type="button" id="restart">RESTART</button>
  <button type="button" id="stop">STOP</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single change that has to be done in you code to make it work as expected.
Just replace the below function block and run the code:

function Update() {
counter++;
document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML = "The counter is now at!" + counter;
timeoutID = window.setTimeout("Update();", 2000);
}

this solution should work for you.